# How to avoid nesting in Serializer on has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, active-model-serializers

I have ProfileSerializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :role, :name
  has_one :company
end
```

and I get

```
{"user": {"id":7,"role":"guest","name":"misa","company":{"id":2,"user_id":7, ...}}
```

I there any chance to avoid "company" nesting and get JSON like this:

```
{"user": {"user_info": {"id":7,"role":"guest","name":"misa"}, "company_info": {"id":2,"user_id":7, ...}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
class ProfileSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :role, :name, :company_info

  def company_info
    object.company
  end
end
```